# How to dynamically add stockEvents to amCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have a function I'm using to add new data points to my stock chart. I need to create a condition under which one of the data points comes with an icon. I see that `stockEvents` can do this but it's not showing in my chart:

```
function addDataPoint(ask) {
        var dataProvider = chart.dataSets[0].dataProvider;
        var newDate = new Date(dataProvider[dataProvider.length - 1].date.getTime());
        newDate.setHours(newDate.getHours(), newDate.getMinutes() + 1, newDate.getSeconds());
        var a = Math.round(Math.random() * (40 + 1000)) + 100 + 1000;
        var b = Math.round(Math.random() * 100000000);
        dataProvider.push({
            date: newDate,
            value: ask,
            volume: ask
        });
        chart.dataSets[0].stockEvents = [{
            date: newDate,
            type: "flag",
            text: "F",
            description: "Some longer\ntext can also\n be added"
        }];
        dataProvider.shift();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the stock event's [`graph`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockEvent#graph) property in order for it to be visible. This can be a reference to the stock graph object, or the graph's [`id`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#id). You also need to call [`validateData`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#validateData) in order to update the chart if you aren't already doing so outside of your addDataPoint function.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "panels": [{
    // ...
    "stockGraphs": [{
       // ...
       "id": "g1", //added id
       // ...
    },
    // ...
    ]
  },
  // ...
  ],
  // ...
});
// ...
function addDataPoint(ask) {
  // ...
  chart.dataSets[0].stockEvents = [{
    date: newDate,
    type: "flag",
    text: "F",
    graph: "g1", //added
    description: "Some longer\ntext can also\n be added"
  }];
  dataProvider.shift();
  chart.validateData(); //added
}
```

Also note that you're overwriting the stockEvents array each time in your addDataPoint function. If you want to preserve your previous event, then you need to use `push` since it's an array.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zf2nc340/)